# How do I ping a .onion address in python?

Tags: python-3.x, url, web, ping, tor

I am writing a program that generates .onion URLs and then checks to see if that URL is real. How do I ping a .onion URL? The URLs generated by my program are in the format ***xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onion***. If this means anything, I am not new to Python itself but I am completely new to using python for networking so please make the example code easy to figure out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? How are you handling the SOCKS5/proxy connection and session? Or were you expecting someone to write your application for you?

Comment: @Dan I am not expecting anyone to write the application for me. I just want to know how to do what I asked. I have not tried anything yet because I don't know how to ping a .onion address in python.

Comment: You should start with [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/), (which a Google search for "python tor" will show as the top result).

Comment: You can't "ping" it in the traditional sense.  You need to try to connect to it over the Tor network and check if you're able to connect and get a response or not.  So basically you need to run Tor locally, and try to connect to it using Tor's SOCKS proxy and see if you time out or get a response.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've sorted out the connection and all you're looking for is a status maybe you could use Requests?:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

```
>>> import requests
>>> ping = requests.get('http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion')
>>> ping.status_code
200
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my torcrawler in python, feel free to use it:

https://github.com/marncz/torcrawler

You need to use proxy and have TOR running on your machine. Torcrawler uses database to store links and go even deeper with every iteration, you can see how to get source and parse websites.

Comment: How do I use it in my code? Do I just import it and then do something like: `to_ping = getUrls.py(random_generated_address)`?

Comment: downlooad project, look at file getUrls.py and replace the link there, work out what you need to get it to work, it is a simple clean project